# Create Box2D and engine polygon Box2D body without sprite

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have created my body using following code: (please read full description)

```
    Body polyBody;
    final BodyDef mBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    mBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    mBodyDef.position.x = 20;
    mBodyDef.position.y = 5;
    polyBody= mPhysicsWorld.createBody(mBodyDef);       
    final PolygonShape mPoly = new PolygonShape();
    mPoly.set(vertices);
    objectFixtureDef.shape = mPoly;
    polyBody.createFixture(objectFixtureDef);
    mPoly.dispose();
```

Now it's time for connecting my polygon with body using `PhysicsConnector`
and when I do `mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mPoly, polyBody, true, true));` it doesn't accept `mPoly` as I expect an `IAreaShape` instead.

Is there any way that I can change it into an `IAreaShape`? Or can anyone suggest how can I create a body without using sprite? It's strictly prohibited that I can't use sprite as I need to cut/slice my body further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working with AndEngine.
You misunderstood the concept of PhysicsConnector. PhysicsConnector need sprite and body to create. But here mPoly is a PolygonShape object that has functionality of box2d not of sprite.

If you don't want to use sprite then there is no need of PhysicsConnector. Basically PhysicsConnector used to attach sprite with body. So developer does not need to render it manually.

Also you have to use pixel to meter ratio to apply position and size of the object. In AndeEngine you can use constant with PhysicsConstant.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO.